# Enqueue file in VLC stream

Tags: vlc-media-player, streaming

I can stream an XSPF playlist with VLC, what I'm trying to do is have it be dynamic. I have a folder where I put all the files I need to stream, and I want VLC to keep streaming and updating the queue when I add files to the folder.

I need to first be able to stream the content of a folder (do I absolutely need to create an XSPF?), and then update the queue when something changes.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use one of the control interfaces like rc, this way you can have a script add files from a directory to the playlist.  https://wiki.videolan.org/Console/